# Using php://input and file_put_contents

Tags: php, ajax

I'm receiving files (images) uploaded with Ajax into my PHP script and have got it to work using this:

```
$input = fopen("php://input", "r");
file_put_contents('image.jpg', $input);
```

Obviously I will sanitize input before this operation.

One thing I wanted to check was the file size prior to creating the new file, as follows:

```
$input = fopen("php://input", "r");
$temp = tmpfile();
$realsize = stream_copy_to_stream($input, $temp);
if ($realsize === $_SERVER["CONTENT_LENGTH"]) {
  file_put_contents('image.jpg', $temp);
}
```

And that doesn't work. The file is created, but it has a size of 0 bytes, so the content isn't being put into the file. I'm not awfully familiar with using streams, but I don't see why that shouldn't work, so I'm turning to you for help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How exactly are you uploading it in the webbrowser? Normally, you'd like to use `multipart/form-data` form encoding and then grab the uploaded file by `$_FILES`. With `php://input` you're indicating that you expect the file to cover the ENTIRE request body. This suggests that you're using a proprietary approach to upload the file in webbrowser. A custom applet maybe?

Comment: I'm reading the `files` collection of the `<input type="file">` element, and simply sending the `file` via the XHR `send()` method. There is no `<form>` being used, as I don't want to use iframes. This is only supported by Firefox and Chrome (not sure about Safari) at the moment.

Comment: Please enable error reporting and display errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution was deceptively simple:

```
$input = fopen("php://input", "r");
file_put_contents($path, $input);
```

Comment: is this method considered safe?

Answer (score 1):

You are using file resources as if they were strings. Instead you could again use `stream_copy_to_stream`:

```
stream_copy_to_stream($temp, fopen('image.jpg', 'w'));
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I just gave that a go and it doesn't work.

Comment: The error was: Warning: file_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given.

Comment: Thanks, that works - but only if you do `fseek($temp, 0, SEEK_SET);` first. So I guess it works, but not with file_put_contents - I'm still interested in knowing why in my original post the first bit of code works, but not after creating the temp file. In other words, I still want to know how to do this with file_put_contents. :)

Comment: @Rafael: file_put_contents expects a file *name*. tempfile gives a file *resource*. If you want to get a temporary file name, use tempnam.