# How to append a POST HTTP request data to a text file in PHP?

Tags: php

What I need is a local web server appending all the POSTed data to a text file. The actual idea is to implement [this (*Storing into file using JavaScript/GreaseMonkey*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392103/storing-into-file-using-javascript-greasemonkey). I think the fastest way is to use XAMPP. The problem is I have forgotten PHP many years ago and have no idea how to do this, though I believe it is easy (no error handling or security required, just a quick-and-dirty one-time solution).

Would you be so kind to suggest a code for this?

Comment: How about you learn php again or pay someone to do it?

Comment: 347 questions and still no clue [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) :P

Comment: [`php://input`](http://php.net/wrappers.php#refsect2-wrappers.php-unknown-unknown-descriptiop) - And if you think the fastest way is to use XAMPP, please contact XAMPP for your support options how to do that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using php://input and file\_put\_contents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005708/using-php-input-and-file-put-contents)

Comment: Yikes.... you need to stop being a stinge OP :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be thrown off by the mention of XAMPP in the question, but XAMPP is a pain.  If you are able, installing a LAMP / MAMP / WAMP server setup manually is the way to go.  Just Google the appropriate type (Windows, Linux, Mac) and you will find there's lots of good write-ups on how to achieve your installation.

Then, capturing the code with some PHP is trivial, and storing it to a file is trivial.  It's fairly straightforward to loop over the post data:

```
$values = '';
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
    $values.= $key . "=" . $value . "\t";
}
```

Then, writing it to the file:

```
$filename = 'my_post_data.txt';
$handle = fopen($filename, 'w');
fwrite($handle, $values);
fclose($handle);
```

This of course is very generic, but is intended as a primer to get you going on your project.  Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much, @cale_b, this is it. The only thing to add is that this replaces the file contents instead of appending - I had to replace the last 3 lines with `file_put_contents($filename, $values, FILE_APPEND);` to do the job (found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335885/php-add-string-to-text-file).

Comment: And I still believe XAMPP is the fastest and easiest way. I have tried  many ways to set a development AMP server up in my life and this is still my favourite, less than a minute to up and running the way I want.